# Change nomencl sort order of groups (not within groups)?

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl, makeindex

To produce an index of notation, I'm using the `nomencl` package, and the various notations will be grouped. I know how to change the sort order of items within a group. But is there a way to change the default order of the groups themselves—*without* renaming the group keys?

For example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}
\usepackage{xstring}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Notation}
\renewcommand*{\pagedeclaration}[1]{\unskip, {#1}}
\newlength{\nomitemorigsep}
\setlength{\nomitemorigsep}{\nomitemsep}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}

\newcommand{\nomenclheader}[1]{%
\item[\hspace*{-\itemindent}\normalfont\bfseries#1]}

\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \itemsep\nomitemorigsep%
  \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
   {L}{\nomenclheader{Logic}}%
   {V}{\nomenclheader{Variables}}%
   {E}{\nomenclheader{Set theory}}%
  }%
  \itemsep\nomitemsep% Restore spacing
}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

The logical notation $p \implies q$ means ``if $p$, then $q$''; the statement $p \iff q$ means ``$p \implies q$ and $q \implies p$''.
\nomenclature[l1]{$p \implies q$}{if $p$, then $q$}
\nomenclature[l2]{$p \iff q$}{$p$ is logically equivalent to $q$}

\newpage

Generally, we use lower-case letters $x$, $y$, $z$, etc., for elements of sets; upper-case letters $A$, $B$, $C$, etc., for sets; and script letters $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{B}$, etc., for collections of sets.
\nomenclature[v1]{$x$, $y$, $z$, etc.}{elements of sets}
\nomenclature[v2]{$A, B, C, \dots, X, Y, Z$}{sets}
\nomenclature[v3]{$\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{B}$, $\mathcal{C}$, etc.}{collections of sets}

\newpage

For a set $A$ and an object $x$, write $x \in A$ to mean that $x$ is an element of $A$.
\nomenclature[e1]{$x \in A$}{$x$ is an element of $A$}
Then $A \subset B$ means that for every $x$, $x \in A \implies x \in B$.
\nomenclature[e2]{$A \subset B$}{$A$ is a subset of $B$}

\printnomenclature[3.5cm]

\end{document}
```

The resulting nomenclature output is:

[image: Unwanted ordering of groups in nomenclature]

But I want the groups to be in the order:

1. Logic
2. Variables
3. Set theory

Of course, I could simply change the names of the keys `L`, `V`, `E` to, say, `L`, `N`, `S`, respectively, to accomplish what I want. However:

- in the actual document, there are a larger number of nomenclature groups, so that simply reassigning the key letter names would not be so straightforward as that; and
- I really do want to use the key letters  `L`, `V`, `E`, as shown in the source, for their mnemonic value (keys I can readily remember without having to refer repeatedly to their meaning).